# Prove that distance between the two sets is $0$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I need to show that distance between the sets $y =0$ and $y = e^{-x}$ is $0$ under $d_2$ metric

Now let $A = \{(x,0)|x \in \mathbb{R}\}$

$B = \{(x,e^{-x})|x \in \mathbb{R}\}$

$d(A,B) = \text{inf} \{d(x,y)|x \in A, y \in B\}$

Now, suppose I pick the sequence $x_n =  (n,0) \in A$ and $y_n = (n,e^{-n}) \in B$, then

$d(x,y) = \sqrt{0 + e^{-2n}}  \to 0$ , as $n \to \infty$

Hence, there exist a sequence $(x_n,y_n)$ such that $d(x_n,y_n)\to  0$, therefore $d(A,B) = 0$

Is this proof correct ?

Please tell me if there are any errors.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: The infimum of $d(x_n,y_n)$ is $0$ but why is the infimum of $d(x,y)=0$? You didn't argue that. It is trivial indeed but just for the sake of completeness....

Comment: Just some small notes: presumably you mean $x_n:=(n,0)$ and $y_n:=(n,e^{-n})$ rather than $x\in (n,0)$ and $y\in (n,e^{-n})$, and $d(x_n,y_n)\to 0$ rather than $d(x_n,y_n)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you have :

$$\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, 0\leq \inf\{d(x,y)|x\in A, y\in B \}\leq d(x_n,y_n) $$

And by passing to the limit in the inequality, you get :
$$0\leq \inf\{d(x,y)|x\in A, y\in B \}\leq0 $$

So $d(A,B)=0$